# Azure App Registration Certificate vs secret

Tags: azure-active-directory, x509certificate, asp.net-core-2.1

I currently have azure app registrations setup for authentication with Open ID connect using JWT. I have an app secret configured in appsettings.json , however i have read that using a certificate is better. Why is this?

Not one for posting ambiguous or discussion posts but i'm a bit stuck. I have found some Microsoft guides for configuring the certificate by creating a self signed certificate but other than that i can't find any decent documentation about what's involved.

Comment: What exactly you wanted to know? Certificate and secret comparison?

Comment: well, yes. I'm trying to ascertain if simply generating a self signed cert is the correct thing to do, whilst doing so i just thought why am i actually doing this? Is this more secure because i dont have to store the secret in a config file somewhere? What if i were to store the secret in azure keyvault? is that acceptable. I just have it in my head that the secret method is temporary and not meant for production.

Comment: If you have any more query feel free to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you wanted to use azure key vault for certificate and secret then probably you have taken a right decision.

As you may know cloud applications and services use cryptographic keys and secrets to help keep information secure. 
For highly sensitive data, you should consider additional layers of protection for data. Encrypting data using a separate protection key prior to storage in [Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview) is worthwhile for example.

**Azure Key Vault** safeguards these keys and secrets. When you use Key Vault, you can encrypt authentication keys, storage account keys, data encryption keys, .pfx files, and passwords by using keys that are protected by hardware security modules.

You can check for more details [here](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

**Access Your Key Vaults More securely**

You may need to access your key vault more securely because of its data sensitivity learn more  about [Secure access to a key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault)

**How secret and Certificate collaborate with azure key vault**

Also for key vault **secret and certificate** you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates)

**Azure key vault quick start**

Setting up and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using the Azure portal you can quickly start from [Microsoft official document for azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Why would you not want to use the existing store that comes as part of the app registration in Azure AD? are they the same technologies? is that simply a key vault anyway but just a special kind of one that comes with the azure app registration whose sole purpose is have either a secret key or an certificate?

Comment: @MrKobayashi In azure AD we cannot store bulk amount secret key and certificate, Imagine you have thousand of application secret and password for your corporate business wouldn't it be worthwhile to manage, this is why azure key vault provide you this functionality.

Comment: I think the comparison is not answered.  Client secrets usually end up in code, certificates are easier to handle and rotate (if you stick to SN+I validation), that's why they're "better".